# Java - Constants class design

Tags: java

I'm new to Android & Java programming but have been programming in .NET for many years.  We've recently developed an android app and it's now in the final stage to be prepped for the customer (not via the market/google play btw).  At any rate, while cleaning up the code. I've noticed we use a TON of strings and I'd like to cut down on this if possible.  I've read a few articles and took the suggestion that anything the end-user may see, I put it in the strings.xml (for better localization, not too sure what they mean by that) but we also use SQLite table names, column names, etc. and I'd like to know the best way to construct a class (or set of classes) that allows us (my developers and I) to access them with ease.

This is how I started to construct it but **wanted some opinions as to if there's a better way (design, performance issues, etc.)**

```
public class Constants {

    static enum SQLiteTableNames { Issues, Activities }

    static class SQLiteTables {
        static class Issues {           
            static class ColumnNames {
                static String ID = "_id";
                static String DateReceived = "DateReceived";
            }
        }

        static class IssueActivites {           
            static class ColumnNames {
                static String ID = "_id";
                static String IssueID = "IssueID";
                static String ActivityDate = "ActivityDate";
                static String ActivityType = "ActivityType";
                static String FullName = "FullName";
                static String Notes = "Notes";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows us to reference column names like so:

```
Constants.SQLiteTables.IssueActivites.ColumnNames.ActivityDate;
```

Should I use final static on the properties instead of just static?

Comment: I cringe when I see a class called Constants.

Comment: Suggestions for another name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constants should be `static final`. This does have a performance benefit, as it allows the value to be compiled in. It's also just good style.

By the way, the convention is to put constant names in `ALL_CAPS`.

Comment: I would also make the classes interfaces - it doesn't make sense for someone to be able to instantiate these classes

Comment: You should probably make the constants public static final string and make the constructor for the constant class private to prevent instantiation.

Comment: @ChrisWhite It doesn't make sense for someone to be able to implement them either. Hence the reason why classes that only have static members, such as `Math` in the JDK, often have private constructors.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments/suggestions...it was very helpful!

Comment: @Taymon - true, but these classes (Math) are typically utility classes that maintain no state, just perform functions. Interfaces cannot contain logic, and are therefore (in my opinion) better for holding constants only